# order entryes have multiple product with sold quantity how to get the top sold products based on how many products are sold

Tags: mysql, sql, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

like i have 1000 order entry in each entry i have multiple products with sold quantity for top selling products.heaare my challange is i need return the top sold products
example:

```
order entry  : product id  :sold quantity;;;;
entry 1     : productA    :20 
            :productB     :10
             :productC     :5
entry 2      :productB     :5
             :productc      :20
```

how can get the top selling product.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is aggregation with `order by`:

```
select product_id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity
from t
group by product_id
order by total_quantity desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: select {product}, sum{quantity} as totalquantity from {orderentry} groupby {product} order by totalquantity desc limit 10. i tries this query but this is taking lot of time . hoiw can i optimise this query

Comment: @ManiSankar . . . I think you asked a new question about that topic.  Unaccepted this answer is not going to get you close to a solution.

Comment: select {p.pk} from {
order as o 
join OrderStatus as os on {os.pk}={o.status}
join orderentry as oe on{oe.order}={o.pk}
join product as p on {oe.product}={p.pk}
}
where {os.code}='COMPLETED' 
AND {o.date}>'2020-08-16 00:00:00.000' AND{o.date}<'2020-09-30 00:00:00.000' group by{p.pk}order by count({oe.pk}) desc limit 10

i wrote this query but i sttruck with how to get all roducts inseted of only pk